# SVG dimensions permanently changed on hover

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg

I'm playing around with Snap and a certain problem occurred to me.
I've got [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/46mduyg2/), I wasn't able to set it up right on JSFiddle because I'm not much used to it, so [here's the working version](http://hissvard.altervista.org/SVG-Snap/boxGradient.html).
What I'm trying to achieve is having it widen when hovering and reset back when the mouse leaves it, and I'm using these two functions to achieve so:

```
function shiftBox(box) {
  box.animate({
    width: parseInt(box.node.getAttribute("width")) + 50,
    height: parseInt(box.node.getAttribute("height")) + 50,
    x: parseInt(box.node.getAttribute("x")) - 25,
    y: parseInt(box.node.getAttribute("y")) - 25
    }, 1500, mina.elastic);
  }

function resetBox(box) {
  box.animate({
    width: parseInt(box.node.getAttribute("width")) - 50,
    height: parseInt(box.node.getAttribute("height")) - 50,
    x: parseInt(box.node.getAttribute("x")) + 25,
    y: parseInt(box.node.getAttribute("y")) + 25
    }, 1500, mina.elastic);
}
```

However, when hovering through it at high speeds the dimensions change permanently and it shifts a bit to the upper left. What I guess happens is that a function gets called before the other has had the time to fully change the values.
Is there a JS function that can make a function wait until the other has finished or should I store the values I need to reset it back beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the original values so you can always go back to them. FWIW your code does not work in a fiddle because it's cross-origin blocked.

```js
var s = Snap('#svg');


  rect = s.selectAll('.rect');
  text = s.select('.text');

  var shifters = [];

  for (i = 0, l = rect.length; i < l; ++i) {
    shifters.push(new Shifter(rect[i]));
  }

  text.hover(function() {
    for (i = 0, l = rect.length; i < l; ++i) {
      shifters[i].shiftBox();
    }
  }, function() {
    for (i = 0, l = rect.length; i < l; ++i) {
      shifters[i].resetBox();
    }
  });



function Shifter(box) {
    this.box = box;
    this.x = box.node.x.baseVal.value;
    this.y = box.node.y.baseVal.value;
    this.width = box.node.width.baseVal.value;
    this.height = box.node.height.baseVal.value;
}
 
Shifter.prototype.shiftBox = function() {
  this.box.animate({
    width: this.width + 50,
    height: this.height + 50,
    x: this.x - 25,
    y: this.y - 25
  }, 1500, mina.elastic);
};

Shifter.prototype.resetBox = function() {
  this.box.animate({
    width: this.width,
    height: this.height,
    x: this.x,
    y: this.y
  }, 1500, mina.elastic);
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <svg id="svg" height="100%" width="100%">
    <rect class="rect" x="0" y="0" fill="#540018" width="600" height="600"/>
<rect class="rect" x="25" y="25" fill="#660022" width="550" height="550"/>
<rect class="rect" x="50" y="50" fill="#75002D" width="500" height="500"/>
<rect class="rect" x="75" y="75" fill="#7F0034" width="450" height="450"/>
<rect class="rect" x="100" y="100" fill="#8C0040" width="400" height="400"/>
<rect class="rect" x="125" y="125" fill="#99004D" width="350" height="350"/>
<rect class="rect" x="150" y="150" fill="#AA005D" width="300" height="300"/>
<rect class="rect" x="175" y="175" fill="#BA006F" width="250" height="250"/>
<rect class="rect" x="200" y="200" fill="#CE0084" width="200" height="200"/>
<rect class="rect" x="225" y="225" fill="#E2009D" width="150" height="150"/>
<text class="text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 244.3037 287.0989)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'Perpetua'" font-size="36">HOVER</tspan><tspan x="14.643" y="43.2" font-family="'Perpetua'" font-size="36">HERE</tspan></text>
<rect class="trigger" x="225" y="225" fill="none" width="150" height="150"/>

  </svg>
  <script src="http://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/raw/master/dist/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

</body>
```